How is a black body 'radiating' light different from 'reflecting' it?
Light falls on a black body and its oscillating electric field causes the electrons to start vibrating, thus gaining kinetic energy which contributes to rise in temperature and, simultaneously, the oscillating electrons emit their own radiations which is why a black body is constantly emitting radiations at non-zero kelvin temperature.
But how is this different from reflection? Is reflected radiation simply the radiation that gets remitted from the surface?

I don't know the answer, but they must be different mechanisms because reflected light always has the same wavelength as the incident light. Blackbody radiation spectrum, on the other hand, is dependent only on the temperature of the object, and not on the wavelength of the incident light.

In reflection, photons maintain their original energy and just change direction, while in black body radiation, the energy is first absorbed, thermalized, and then re-emitted at different wavelengths based on the temperature. a perfect blackbody by definition does not reflect any light. All its radiation come from thermal radiation. From another angle, reflection is not part of blackbody radiation since the energy does not go through thermalization.

so if an atomic electron in the ground state absorbs a photon and jumps to an excited state...doesn't the kinetic energy decrease? js.

Reflection is a general process that happens with waves, when it encounters the interface between two media with different refraction index, for example. For the light, the conditions to have total or partial reflection depends on the properties of the material, like electric permissibility and magnetic permeability. Microscopically, it can be linked to electronic movement in metals, for example, as you said. But everything could be described by macroscopic quantities related to the material considered.
Black body radiation, on the other hand, is not related to material properties. It is a consequence of thermal equilibrium of electromagnetic field. Kirchhoff showed that if we have an electromagnetic field in thermal equilibrium with a perfect idealized material, its energy density should depend only on the temperature and (if we consider frequency decomposition) frequency. Later in 1917, Einstein showed that blackbody radiation is a consequence of equilibrium of three processes that happens in the interaction between light and matter: spontaneous emission, stimulated emission and absorption. But the hole process can be explained without assuming specific properties of the materia in question.

Blackbody radiation doesn't depend on material properties because it is the radiation that would be produced by an idealized material with "default" properties. Real materials don't emit a perfect blackbody spectrum because they have real-world properties that modify their radiation spectrum.

How did Kirchhoff show this independence of material properties, if his very law tells that the spectrum of thermal radiation depends on the spectrum of absorptivity of material?

You're right, that's the reciprocity between emission and absorption properties. As the comment of @ThePhoton above explain, the black body spectrum refers to idealized material.

In the first part of this article that you mentioned, we find: "For a body of any arbitrary material emitting and absorbing thermal electromagnetic radiation at every wavelength in thermodynamic equilibrium, the ratio of its emissive power to its dimensionless coefficient of absorption is equal to a universal function only of radiative wavelength and temperature. That universal function describes the perfect black-body emissive power." I edited the answer to make it clearer

Blackbody radiation doesn't depend on there being any incoming light at all. Reflection does:
The coals from a fire emit light for a time even after the fire is extinguished because they are still hot.  As they cool down, they emit less light (and the emitted spectrum shifts from visible to the infrared).  The temperature of a material can be determined just by examining the emitted spectrum.  That spectrum will be continuous and is best measured in the dark, without any impinging light. Mechanically, the light is generated by electrons moving from high-energy states to lower-energy states throughout the material. Blackbody radiation is the same for all materials at a given temperature.
A mirror reflects light because light is incident on it and the electrons at the surface respond to the electric field in the light (an EM wave).  As the electrons short out the electric field, the Poynting vector flips, changing the direction of the light and bouncing it back.  Reflection thus depends on their being a substantial number of "free" electrons which move easily between different states and atoms.
If you heat silver to temperatures of a few hundred degrees, it'll glow red due to blackbody radiation (like the coals of a fire would at the same temperature) but will also reflect light (since the electrons can move freely).  You could make a mirror from the reflective, molten surface, but rather than seeing your reflection as you would in a cold mirror, you would see a reddened version of yourself & your background. The hot mirror would glow in the dark due to blackbody radiation.

If you heat a polished metal surface red hot, it glows with light it emits even if it is dark out. Reflected light comes from outside and bounces off.
A red hot mirror would not show a red image. Red light would be absorbed and make the mirror slightly hotter. The light would be emitted as a glow.

You have to ask yourself what happens to the part of the daylight that is not reflected by a colored body. A body painted blue reflects blue quite well, but what happens to the other wavelengths?
A good assumption is that the light is absorbed and disappears in the body. This transports energy into the body.
This leads to a stronger thermal vibration of the body's molecules. It is interesting to note that the vibrations are constantly spreading (dissipation) and their frequency decreases.
As the molecules on the surface of the body also vibrate, infrared radiation is emitted from there. In general, every body always emits because of the molecular vibrations. A well reflecting body has intensity peaks for certain wavelengths, but IR is always emitted there too. If the body is also heated, the IR radiation becomes more intense and even luminous in the visible range if sufficient energy is supplied.
But what makes blackbody radiation so interesting?  It has been measured that the distribution of radiation intensity for all wavelengths depends only on the temperature of the body. No matter with which frequencies I exposure the body and no matter what the body is made of. All incoming light dissipates in the body according to the same scheme and is only dependent on the temperature of the body.
Not particularly interesting? Well, but it led to Planck quantizing light radiation to calculate blackbody radiation. And Einstein postulated light from quanta. Later, these quanta were called photons.
